# Replace decimal separator in string which is not numeric

Tags: c#

How to replace all decimal separators in a text with a custom separator?

Examples:

- `xyz,1,23.4yz` should be with dot-separtor `xyz,1.23.xyz`
- `xyz,1.23.4yz` should be with comma-separtor `xyz,1,23.xyz`

I wrote this test case for it:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("0,05 - 2", "0,05 - 2", "0.05 - 2")]
[InlineData("0,1  ,5", "0,1  ,5", "0.1  ,5")]
[InlineData("0,1 - 2,0", "0,1 - 2,0", "0.1 - 2.0")]
[InlineData("0,234", "0,234", "0.234")]
[InlineData("123,4", "123,4", "123.4")]
[InlineData("12.345,6789", "12,345,6789", "12.345.6789")]
[InlineData("xyz,1,23.4yz", "xyz,1,23,4yz", "xyz,1.23.4yz")]
[InlineData("xyz5,1,23,xyz", "xyz5,1,23,xyz", "xyz5.1.23,xyz")]
[InlineData("0.05 - 2", "0,05 - 2", "0.05 - 2")]
[InlineData("0.1  .5", "0,1  .5", "0.1  .5")]
[InlineData("0.1 - 2.0", "0,1 - 2,0", "0.1 - 2.0")]
[InlineData("0.234", "0,234", "0.234")]
[InlineData("123.4", "123,4", "123.4")]
[InlineData("12345.6789", "12345,6789", "12345.6789")]
[InlineData("xyz.1.23.4yz", "xyz.1,23,4yz", "xyz.1.23.4yz")]
[InlineData("xyz5,1.23,xyz", "xyz5,1,23,xyz", "xyz5.1.23,xyz")]
public void Convert(string input, string resultComma, string resultDot)
{
  string expectedResultComma = new ConverterDecimal(",").Convert(input);
  expectedResultComma.Should().Be(resultComma);

  string expectedResultDot = new ConverterDecimal(".").Convert(input);
  expectedResultDot.Should().Be(resultDot);
}
```

The only solution I know is to check each "word" if it's a number and parse it to decimal. I am wondering that I found no solution for this question :)

Comment: Your example, `xyz,1.23.xyz`, still contains a comma. What's the rule that you're trying to implement?

Comment: And the source example `xyz,1,23.4yz` doesn't match the output `xyz,1,23.4yz`. The `4` has been replaced with an `x`. You need to be very clear about the examples and the rules you need.

Comment: The more I look at your examples, the more confused I am. Can you please read [ask] and then really very very precisely describe your rule?

Comment: The data for the test gives the input string, then the expected result for converting to comma and then for dot seperator for decimal values. I am also confused about this task :)

Comment: I added a second example. Hope it is more clear now @Enigmativity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try to state the problem in a different way; according to examples provided, we, probably, can put it as

> Replace every comma `,` which is surrounded by digits `0..9` into dot `.`

If it's your case, you can try *regular expressions*, we can try `(?<=[0-9]),(?=[0-9])` pattern:

```
  (?<=[0-9]) - look behind for 0..9 digit
  ,          - comma
  (?=[0-9])  - look ahead for 0..9 digit
```

**Code:**

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  private static string ConvertMe(string source) =>
    Regex.Replace(source, @"(?<=[0-9]),(?=[0-9])", ".");
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "0,05 - 2",
    "0,1  ,5",
    "0,1 - 2,0",
    "0,234",
    "123,4",
    "12.345,6789",
    "xyz,1,23.4yz",
    "xyz5,1,23,xyz",
    "0.05 - 2",
    "0.1  .5",
    "0.1 - 2.0",
    "0.234",
    "123.4",
    "12345.6789",
    "xyz.1.23.4yz",
    "xyz5,1.23,xyz",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
   .Select(test => $"{test,20} : {ConvertMe(test)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
        0,05 - 2 : 0.05 - 2
         0,1  ,5 : 0.1  ,5
       0,1 - 2,0 : 0.1 - 2.0
           0,234 : 0.234
           123,4 : 123.4
     12.345,6789 : 12.345.6789
    xyz,1,23.4yz : xyz,1.23.4yz
   xyz5,1,23,xyz : xyz5.1.23,xyz
        0.05 - 2 : 0.05 - 2
         0.1  .5 : 0.1  .5
       0.1 - 2.0 : 0.1 - 2.0
           0.234 : 0.234
           123.4 : 123.4
      12345.6789 : 12345.6789
    xyz.1.23.4yz : xyz.1.23.4yz
   xyz5,1.23,xyz : xyz5.1.23,xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @dmitry-bychenko, I came up with this solution for comman and dot as separators:

```
public string Convert(string input, string separator)
{
  string oldSeparator;
  if (separator.Equals("."))
  {
    oldSeparator = ",";
  }
  else
  {
    oldSeparator = ".";
  }
  var result = Regex.Replace(input, $@"(?<=[0-9])\{oldSeparator}(?=[0-9])", separator);
  return result;
}
```